# Is it possible to read data from the manifest.json using botbuilder sdk?

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, manifest.json

I am building a bot for MS teams. I need to be able to know which app manifest.json was installed in the tenant. Is there a way to pass meta data into manifest.json and then get it on installation event using botbuilder in my app?

Comment: This doesn't seems to be possible yo read data from the manifest.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seems to be possible to read data from the manifest.json using botbuilder sdk.